# xarray select on 2 dimensional coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am using xarray to work with gridded data and the coordinates latitude and longitude are 2dimensional arrays. It is quite similar to on of the tutorial datasets coming along with xarray.

```
ds = xarray.tutorial.open_dataset('rasm').load()
```

Now I want to use the `sel` feature to access data from specific points.

```
ds.sel(yc=50, xc=50, method='nearest')
```

In this example `DataArray` the coordinates `xc` and `yc` are no dimensions, so It is necessary to define them as an index. Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. The reasons why (and path forward) are detailed in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/475.

There are various work arounds available though. You may try using the `groupby_bins` method (e.g. http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html).